# How to make div resizeable having CSS pseudo-elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-resizable

I am giving a star shape to div element with the help of css as below:

```
.star-six {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
.star-six:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 30px;
    left: -50px;
}
```

This css is applied with the help of javascript and I make it resizeable as

```
$('.star-six').resizable();
```

this script only makes the upper triangle of star resizeable and that too it expand in trapezium form when I resize it. Please help me to know how to make the whole star as resizeable.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tF64T/8/) example.

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: A working demo would be nice.

Comment: Is "pseudo CSS" just a fancy name for JavaScript/jQuery or you are really only looking for a description in plain English of what the CSS should look like?

Comment: pseudo css is for ".star-six:before" term as before is use there

Comment: I think the `resizable()` method don't support the pseudo class, you can try with two different overlapped divs

Comment: @enyce12   Sorry I have update the code again please check now  http://jsfiddle.net/tF64T/8/ I have uploaded on jsfiddle

Comment: Alright. That's called a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). You also have [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

Answer (score 2):

I would venture to guess that the `.resizable()` function is applied to the first element only. Try applying it in an `each`:

```
$( ".star-six" ).each(function(i, o) {
  $( o ).resizable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding "resize:both" in CSS would help.

Comment: That surely works, provided you add the code for every class or id.

Comment: Sir, I tried it, it does not work for '.star-six:before' class.